# zip file is being create but without any files in it

Tags: java

i copied this code directly from oracle website. i have two .png file inside d:\barcode. while i run this code myfigs.zip is created in d: drive but it is corruped and 0kb size.

code:-

```
public class Zip {
static final int BUFFER = 2048;
public static void main (String argv[]) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        FileOutputStream dest = new
                FileOutputStream("D:\\myfigs.zip");
        CheckedOutputStream checksum = new
                CheckedOutputStream(dest, new Adler32());
        ZipOutputStream out = new
                ZipOutputStream(new
                BufferedOutputStream(checksum));
        //out.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
        // get a list of files from current directory
        File f = new File("D:\\barcode");
        String files[] = f.list();

        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Adding: "+files[i]);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i]);
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;
            while((count = origin.read(data, 0,
                    BUFFER)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            origin.close();
        }
        out.close();
        System.out.println("checksum: "+checksum.getChecksum().getValue());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

to add more information whenever i run the code in debug mode code is successfully compiled to FileInputStream fi line then it is stopped there. the error thrown is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: barcode.png (The system cannot find the file    specified)
Adding: barcode.png
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception says "file not found". Your "adding" print statement gives you the answer:

```
Adding: barcode.png
```

The file "barcode.png" is not the same as the file "D:\barcode\barcode.png". You're just looking for a file named "barcode.png" in whatever your current working directory is set to, and it isn't there.

As per the docs for [`list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list--) and the conclusion you should have made from your observations of your printed output and exception:

> Names denoting the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not included in the result. Each string is a file name rather than a complete path.

So you need to either:

- Change your working directory to "D:\barcode" first, or
- Add the parent directory name ("D:\barcode") back to the beginning of your filename ("barcode.png") before opening it, or
- [Look at some of the other functions `File` has to offer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) and see if there's one that helps you avoid this problem entirely.

Couple other minor notes:

- It should be no surprise that the zip file was empty, given that your code [threw an exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) before you wrote anything to it.
- *"whenever i run the code in debug mode code is successfully compiled to FileInputStream fi line then it is stopped there"* - This terminology is not correct. Your error was not a compiler error, it was a runtime error. The code compiled just fine.
- The root cause of your problem was blind modification of the code copied from the Oracle site. Note the original comment, *"get a list of files from current directory"* -- This code assumed the files came from the current working directory. When you added your own directory in, that was no longer the case, and the program broke.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort to help me. i added :- 

 FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("D:\\barcode\\"+files[i]);

as per your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You can use as below code for zip one file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

/**
 * Create by Cuder
 *
 */
public class SampleZipFile {

    /**
     * Create by Cuder
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            File fileInput = new File(
                    "D:\\eclipse4.4\\workspace\\SampleJava\\resource\\sampleZipFile.txt");
            File fileOutput = new File(
                    "D:\\eclipse4.4\\workspace\\SampleJava\\resource\\sampleZipFile.zip");

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
            zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileInput);

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileInput.getName());
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                zipOutputStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != fileInputStream) {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                }
                if (null != zipOutputStream) {
                    zipOutputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and the solution in your answer, not in a link.

Comment: This would be more useful if you could explain what the problem was in the OP's code, how it can be solved, and what changes you made to solve it.